# RCA Audio Video Switcher controlled via software

Tags: video-capture

I **am not** an electrical engineer. I am a **software developer**. Currently I have to create a program that allows users to schedule TV programs for a TV station.

When I visited the station I encountered (for the first time in my life) a metal box that has 3 pairs of composite inputs, and a single output. It's a typical **RCA Audio and Video Switcher**. It has no serial number, no brand, it's a plain metal box that almost seems handmade.

A requirement is for the program to switch between the three composite inputs in that metal box **programmatically**. Because the previous developing team is no longer active, there is **zero** documentation for that project. There is no source code, there is nothing.

**My question is**: is there a manufactured RCA Audio Video switcher that (out of the box) allows me to switch between inputs through software (*Node-Webkit*) ?

I have searched but all the results I have come up with are for users to manually switch inputs with either a remote controller or physical switch (in the form of a stick or wheel) located in the switcher itself.